# React-bootstrap: onChange invoked only once for "select"

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Here is a [fiddle with the example](https://jsfiddle.net/tsnzs8rh/2/) demonstrating this code:

```
render: function() {
    return (
      <FormControl componentClass="select" onChange={console.log("changed")}>
                    <option value="1">A</option>         
                    <option value="2">B</option>         
      </FormControl>                       
    );
  }
```

`onChange()` is invoked only when my component gets rendered.

I want to react on a different option. So if I change 'A' to 'B' I want the component to fire `onChange()` event. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a method named `handleSelectChange`

```
handleSelectChange: function(event) {
    //Do sth
}
```

and call it like 
`onChange={this.handleSelectChange}`

Comment: Oh my! I can see the error now! The problem is that I was invoking the function `console.log("changed")`. Instead, I should have passed a reference aka `console.log`.